# Accessing user input taken in while loop (Python)

Tags: python

I want user to enter random numbers.
I run a while loop until the user enters 0.

```
while input()!=0:
    print "Your number is:...??"
```

My question is:
Are there any special variables (like $_ in Perl) using which I can access the user input?
For example (in the above case) I want to print what the user has entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative method is to use `iter` and provide a callable:

```
for num in iter(lambda: int(raw_input('Your number is: ')), 0):
    print 'You entered', num
```

Comment: This is nice.  According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter), the value of the callable will be returned unless it is the sentinel which will raise StopIteration.

Comment: @Jon This is nice method. Thank you. But I never clearly understand what lambda exactly does. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Holmes `lambda` creates a callable... You can think of it as a less flexible `def`... So the above could define `def somefunc(): raw_input('Your number is: ')`  and instead of the lambda, use `somefunc`.... - see http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda

Comment: @Holmes In fairness, I should point out although I prefer this method - it's not an oft-used syntax of the language, so not all Python programmers will immediately grok it - while everyone will grok the `while` and `break` system...

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the result to a variable:

```
s = None
while s != 0:
  s = int(input("Enter number: "))
  print("Your number is: {}".format(s))
```

This is a python3 example.  For python 2.x you should be using `raw_input` instead.

Comment: Hmm.. It seems we can not run this loop without creating a variable. Thank you.